# Is there a way to catenate specific pages from multiple pdfs using pdftk?

Tags: pdftk

So say I have a few pdfs with. Some with a single page, some with 3, 4, 5 and so on…

I want to extract say the 4th page from the pdfs (ignoring ones without the 4th) page and merge them into a single pdf.

Tried something like

$ pdftk *.pdf cat 4 output merged.pdf

Going by this pdftk gives me a single page pdf output with the 4th page of the first input pdf.

Wondering whether I should write an elaborate script or if there’s an easier way

I do have a few workarounds where I burst the pdfs and then merge the pages I need but looking for something simpler.